# Codeigniter url redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used to encrypt the id of my data in my url ex. mywebsite.com/product/detail/encryptedid then if i would go to that link it will show all the info of that specific product. but when i tried to change the encryptedid such as some random string ex. mywebsite.com/product/detail/asd123 it will show the error "Trying to get property of non-object" I'm curious how to prevent it in such a way like if they will change the encrypted url to some random strings it can redirect to the original mywebsite.com/product/detail/encryptedid which will show still the info of that specific product or go to 404 page.

for clear example look at the image below.

**Image with encryption**

[image: with encrypt id]

**Image with inputted random string**

[image: without encrypt id]

**EDITED:**

**My Controller**

```
public function details($id){

    $decrypt = secret_url('decrypt',$id);

    $prod_row = $this->ProductModel->getonerow($decrypt);
    $data['product_detail'] = $prod_row;

    $data['title'] = "Ayos Computer | Product Details";
    $data['category'] = $this->ProductModel->get_category();
    $data['products'] = $this->ProductModel->get_product();

    $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('include/nav');
    $this->load->view('products/ProductDetail', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer');
}
```

**VIEW**

```
 <a href="<?= base_url() .'products/details/' . secret_url('encrypt',$featured_row->product_id) ?>"></a>
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: could you share your code ?

Comment: @shafiq I already edited my question and include the codes.

Comment: what data $featured_row hold ? is object of your product ? check for empty condition. Is error in view or controller ?

Comment: yes it is the object of my product. what do u mean for is error in view or controller? coz what i want to solve is how to avoid or not to show the error "Trying to get property of non-object" every time i tried to write some random strings in the url mywebsite/products/details/

Comment: which line number its showing "Trying to get property of non-object". And I cannot find in your code from where you are passing $featured_row to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As same way as if there was no product:

```
public function details($id)
{

    $decrypt = secret_url('decrypt',$id);

    $prod_row = $this->ProductModel->getonerow($decrypt);

    if (null !== $prod_row) {
        $data['product_detail'] = $prod_row;

        $data['title'] = "Ayos Computer | Product Details";
        $data['category'] = $this->ProductModel->get_category();
        $data['products'] = $this->ProductModel->get_product();

        $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('include/nav');
        $this->load->view('products/ProductDetail', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer');
    } else {
        // CI default 404 view if left blank value
        show_404($custom_page = '');
    }
}
```